# proper way to extract values from string variable of multiple choice question

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset where the participants could choose multiple options simultaneously (from 0 to 5). As a result the variable is a string that can look like

```
0145
0123
012345
234
```

(depending on which choices they've made).

I need to add columns (choice_0, choice_1,..., choice_5) that will be set to true if the corresponding value contains in the string.

Right now I do it like that, but I wonder if there is more pretty way:

```r
  df %>%mutate(source_0 = str_detect(knowledge_type, '0'),
         source_1 = str_detect(knowledge_type, '1'),
         source_2 = str_detect(knowledge_type, '2'),
         source_3 = str_detect(knowledge_type, '3'),
         source_4 = str_detect(knowledge_type, '4'),
         source_5 = str_detect(knowledge_type, '5')
         )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `splitstackshape::cSplit_e` which will return binary values.

```
res <- splitstackshape::cSplit_e(df, 'knowledge_type', 
            type = 'character', sep = '', fill = 0)

res
#  knowledge_type knowledge_type_0 knowledge_type_1 knowledge_type_2
#1           0145                1                1                0
#2           0123                1                1                1
#3         012345                1                1                1
#4            234                0                0                1

#  knowledge_type_3 knowledge_type_4 knowledge_type_5
#1                0                1                1
#2                1                0                0
#3                1                1                1
#4                1                1                0
```

If you need logical values you can add -

```
res[-1] <- res[-1] > 0
res

#  knowledge_type knowledge_type_0 knowledge_type_1 knowledge_type_2
#1           0145             TRUE             TRUE            FALSE
#2           0123             TRUE             TRUE             TRUE
#3         012345             TRUE             TRUE             TRUE
#4            234            FALSE            FALSE             TRUE

#  knowledge_type_3 knowledge_type_4 knowledge_type_5
#1            FALSE             TRUE             TRUE
#2             TRUE            FALSE            FALSE
#3             TRUE             TRUE             TRUE
#4             TRUE             TRUE            FALSE
```

---

A `tidyverse` way using `map_dfc` -

```
library(tidyverse)

bind_cols(df, map_dfc(as.character(0:5), ~df %>% 
          transmute(!!paste0('source', .x) := str_detect(knowledge_type, .x))))

#  knowledge_type source0 source1 source2 source3 source4 source5
#1           0145    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE
#2           0123    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE   FALSE
#3         012345    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
#4            234   FALSE   FALSE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE   FALSE
```